# Maximal entropy distribution in a finite doman with random endpoints

Tags: entropy, mathematical-physics, probability

I am trying to solve for the distribution of a random variable $x$, which will maximise my entropy in a finite domain, let's say $[0, R]$.

$$
S = -\int_0^Rdxp(x)\ln p(x)
$$

The distribution that maximises this entropy is a uniform distribution of the form, $p(x) = 1/R$.

On the other hand, if I set the endpoint $R$ to be a random variable, given by some distribution (let's consider, $p(R) = R^{-1}\exp(-r/R)$), then how can we calculate the maximal entropy distribution?

**Can we use a method similar to Lagrange's multiplier technique?**

Edit 1:

As pointed out by Ninad Munshi in the comments, the entropy itself becomes a random variable in this scenario. Therefore, should we look for another rule (instead of the maximum entropy principle), which can be used to calculate the best distribution?

Comment: That would make $S$ a random variable as well, and random variables aren't "minimized". One could, however, seek to either minimize the expected value of $S$ w.r.t. the $R$ distribution or minimize it's variance. If there is some other notion of minimizing without turning $S$ into a scalar, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: There are the classical articles by Jaynes on the information theory in staistical mechanics: https://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/theory.1.pdf and a few more.

Comment: @NinadMunshi You make a valid point about S becoming a random variable. In that scenario, do you think there would be an altogether different method to find the most suitable distribution (which not the maximum entropy method)?

Comment: I believe that Roger Vadim provides a sensible answer to the question as posed, but from a wider perspective it might be useful to understand what's the "data generating process" and what is your goal for this maximum entropy calculation, because the answer that would be useful for you might depend on this context.

Comment: @Ori I am looking at the motion of molecules in a complex fluid that is strongly networked through hydrogen bonds. I am trying to construct a model which can provide a transiently confined diffusion but with varying radii of confinement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distribution posed can be considered as conditional on the value of $r$, i.e., we have
$$S(r)=-\int_0^Rdxp(x|r)\log p(x|r).$$
We then obtain $$p(x|r)=\frac{\theta(r-x)}{r},$$ where $\theta(x)$ is the step-function. Then the joint distribution is
$$
p(x,r)=p(x|r)p(r)=\frac{\theta(r-x)}{rR}e^{-\frac{r}{R}}.
$$
Marginalizing in respect to $r$ we obtain the distribution of $x$:
$$
p(x)=\int_0^{+\infty}dr p(x,r)=\frac{1}{R}\int_x^{+\infty}\frac{dr}{r}e^{-\frac{r}{R}}=
\frac{1}{R}\int_{\frac{x}{R}}^{+\infty}dt\frac{e^{-t}}{t}=
\frac{E_1(\frac{x}{R})}{R},
$$
where $E_1(z)$ is an [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

**Remark**
If one wished to approach this problem from the point of view of Lagrange multipliers, one could maximize the entropy for the joint distribution function $p(x,r)$ with the constraint that $p(r)$ is given by the form required form:
$$
S = -\int_0^{+\infty}dr\int_0^rdxp(x,r)\log p(x,r) + 
\int_0^{+\infty}dr\lambda(r)\left[\int_0^rdxp(x,r)-p_0(r)\right],\\
p_0(r)=\frac{1}{R}e^{-\frac{r}{R}}
$$
where differentiation in respect to a Lagrange multiplier is replaced by functional variation in respect to $\lambda(r)$.

Comment: Generalizing the answer, for a general distribution $p(r)$ (not necessarily exponential), the functional maximization with Lagrange multiplier yields $p(x,r) = \frac{p(r)}{r}$. Note that there is no problem with integrability when $r\to 0$ because the domain of integration is the triangle $0<x<r$, which becomes vanishingly small when $r$ is small.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting answer. I have a fundamental question (might sound stupid though), is the information content of the conditional probability the same as that of the probability of the independent variable? I just want to clarify if the method entropy maximisation is indeed valid to obtain the right distribution.

Comment: @Ori my mistake regarding the integrability - now corrected.

Comment: @user35952 I have corrected the error that Ori has pointed out in their comments. Regarding your question: you may want to read about [conditional entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy) and [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information). I also recommend [Cover & Thomas](https://www.amazon.com/Elements-Information-Theory-Telecommunications-Processing/dp/0471241954) as the canonical textbook on the information theory.